# Расстояние от картинки до картинки!

Tags: css

Всем привет! Есть одна проблема.. Смотрите, здесь - x Картинки слиплись. Если использовать "padding" то двигается первая картинка от div'а. И ленточка назначина к первой картинки а используется на второй. Помогите!

Comment: Эта проблема у человека, который за деньги создаёт сайты?)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#fix {
 margin-right:10px
}

.wrapper {
float: left;
padding-bottom: 30px;
width: 590px;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin-right: 5px;
```

То есть идея в том чтобы увеличить wrapper на размер отступа